# Soft Delete : Child Entity not being deleted after Deleting parent Entity in @OneToMany relation in Spring Boot JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to implement soft delete between a parent and child entity in such a way that deleting the parent entity would delete all its child entities as well.
My parent entity is `User` with a `@OneToMany` relation with `Profile`. `Profile` is created with a reference to `User`. Deleting the `User` works fine but when trying to retrieve the `Profile` that was referencing the `User`, I get an exception.

```
{
    "title": "Internal Server Error",
    "status": 500,
    "detail": "Unable to find com.user.domain.User with id 951; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.user.domain.User with id 951",
    "path": "/api/profiles",
    "message": "error.http.500"
}
```

#### User.java

```
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"users"})
@ToString(exclude = {"users"})
@Getter
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Profile.Builder.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@SQLDelete(sql="Update users SET deleted = 'true' where id=?")
@Where(clause="deleted != 'true'")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private final String password;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private Gender gender;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "users", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Profile> profiles = new HashSet<>();
    
    @Column(name="deleted")
    String deleteFlag;

}
```

#### Profile.java

```
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"users"})
@ToString(exclude = {"users"})
@Getter
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Profile.Builder.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
@SQLDelete(sql="Update users SET deleted = 'true' where id=?")
@Where(clause="deleted != 'true'")
public class Profile implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private final Long id;

    @Column(name = "profile_name")
    private final String profileName;

    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    private final LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @Column(name = "health_history")
    private final String healthHistory;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "users_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("reports")
    private final User users;

    @Column(name="deleted")
    String deleteFlag;
}
```

Comment: How is it soft delete when deleting the parent entity would delete all its child entities as well.I am not able to understand what are you trying to achieve.Please edit the post and specify scenarios what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem in delete query for profile

```
@SQLDelete(sql="Update users SET deleted = 'true' where id=?")
```

Here you're updating users table. I think it's a problem why your profiles are not removed after deleting User.

Comment: I can't believe I made this mistake. Thank you @Vlad , it's working perfectly now.